# How to implement remote: true for react (rails)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I create the form in this way:

```
= form_for Review.new do |f|
  = react_component "Popups/ReviewPopup", {name: "review-popup"}
```

Inside the `Popup/PreviewPopup` I have a form field with the desired `name`.

And when click on the submit occurs:

```
const SendButton = ({ onSubmit }) => (
  <button
    onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onSubmit(e);

    }}
    className="button popup-footer__button"
  >
    Send
  </button>
);
```

After that, without rebooting, data from the form should be sent and the message should appear in the browser.

During a normal send  everything works perfectly.

How to implement `remote: true`? I want to implement a `remote: true` and not to catch data from fields when the user click and send them using the `axios` to the server.

Comment: `remote: true` just adds a `data-remote` attribute to the form. jQuery Rails adds an ajax event handler to forms (and links) with the `data-remote` attribute. As Зелёный pointed out - its not magic. And its not something you want to use if you are using React as it will just get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rails-ujs` library.

```
import Rails from 'rails-ujs'; // for webpack
```

To submit a form run the next command:

```
Rails.fire(document.getElementByID('FORM-ID'), 'submit');
```